# if I pass selected image using gridview to second fragment , If I want to selected image pass second to third fragment. then how will do?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

As passed the image view .it getting error .

```
    Builder build = new Builder();
    build.putInt("key value" , image view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sent image local path and get pat hand show image